# "mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found"

Tags: python, mysql

I want to execute the function view_accounts() but I receive error says, "mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found"

I tried to replace the calling of view_accounts() but I still receive errors.

Here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
conn = mysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="db_iptech2")

def login(username, password):

    sql = f"SELECT * FROM tbl_account WHERE username = '{username}' AND password = '{password}'"
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    mycursor.fetchone()
    x = mycursor.rowcount
    return x

def register(user, pw, fname, mname, lname):
    sql = f"INSERT INTO tbl_account(username, password, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName) \
                           VALUES ('{user}', '{pw}', '{fname}', '{mname}', '{lname}')"
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
    print("Successfully Registered!")
    mycursor.close()

def view_accounts():
    sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_account"
    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    mycursor.execute(sql2)

    for row in mycursor:
        print(row)

    mycursor.close()

print("(L) Login / (R) Register")
question = input("Execute: ")

if question == 'L':
    user = input("Enter username: ")
    password = input("Enter Password: ")
    x = login(user, password)
    if x > 0:
        print("Welcome to System")
        view_accounts()
    else:
        print("Incorrect username or Password")

elif question == 'R':
    user = input("Enter username: ")
    password = input("Enter password: ")
    fname = input("Enter First Name: ")
    mname = input("Enter Middle Name: ")
    lname = input("Enter Last Name: ")

    register(user, password, fname, mname, lname)
```

Comment: I just need to execute the view_accounts() function but its not working please help.

Comment: Thanks! I just got the solution my self. What I did is I just place the connection string inside each functions. And that solves the issue. Try it.